# System table where I can find the type of dataschema for a table

Tags: sybase

Is there a system table that contain the type of dataschema for a table ?

> > alter table TBD lock datapages

I want to know if there is a table where I can I find that table TBD have datapages

is there such systable ?

Comment: select 
name
, 'table uses...' = case (sysstat2 & 57344)
when 8192 then 'allpages locking scheme'
when 16384 then 'datapages locking scheme'
when 32768 then 'datarows locking scheme'
end
from sysobjects where type = "U"

Comment: If this is the answer, you should go ahead and make it the accepted answer.  It's ok to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This select helped me

```
select name , 'table uses...' = case (sysstat2 & 57344) when 8192 then
  'allpages locking scheme' when 16384 then 'datapages locking scheme' 
when 32768 then 'datarows locking scheme' end from sysobjects where type = "U"
```